# How should the ending of 2 Peter 2:11 read?

Tags: textual-criticism, 2-peter

[Related to this question](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/5798/who-is-being-slandered-in-2-peter-10b-11), I noticed that the ending of 2 Peter 2:11 is translated respectively by the NIV and ESV as "from the Lord" and "before the Lord." From what I can tell this seems to be owing to a difference in manuscripts. Which rendering was most likely the original rendering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As best I can tell, there is no major difference in the wording seen in the oldest extant manuscripts dated closest to any original text of 2 Peter. Specifically:

1. P72 (ca. 275-325 CE) shows ΠΑΡΑΚΥΡΙΟΥΒΛΑΣΦΗΜΟΝΚΡΙΣΙΝ (παρα κυριου βλασφημον κρισιν), and
2. similarly, codex *Vaticanus* (ca. 325-375 CE) reads ΠΑΡΑΚ̅ WΒΛΑΣΦΗΜΟΝΚΡΙϲῙ (παρα κω βλασφημον κρισι̅ ).

Also, there is scholarship indicating that:

> "In order to avoid attributing *βλάσφημον κρίσιν* [accusation, demeaning judgment, reproaching charge] to God, scribes altered *κυριου* [in western texts] to *κυριω* [in eastern texts] or omitted the prepositional phrase entirely as in [codex Alexandrianus, et al.]" (Metzger, *TCGNT* 633).

The key Greek word in these clauses, IMO, is ΠΑΡΑ (παρα/*para*). This preposition properly means **near**, yet can be correctly translated from Greek into English as (*inter alia*) either **before** or **from**. Which word to use is dependent upon which English preposition the translator/translation committee thinks might best express the thought s/he or they wish to convey.

Also, there's no help available from any of the church fathers as to which preposition might be most correct.